# Dictionary vs List of Variables

Tags: c#, xna

I'm creating something that requires me to have quite a substantial amount of textures loaded (Using XNA's Texture2D) and I've been using a method that has made managing them slightly easier (As I'm constantly changing the names of the textures etc).

My current code is as follows:

```
public static Dictionary<String, Texture2D> textureList = new Dictionary<string, Texture2D>();

public void AddTexture(String title)
{
    Texture2D texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(title); // This is just XNA's way of loading a texture
    textureList.Add(title, texture);

    Console.WriteLine("Texture bounds: " + textureList["ImageTitle"].Bounds); // AN example of the texture system being used
}
```

This now allows me to just simply do `AddTexture("Sprinkler");` when I wish to be adding a new texture and (as shown in the example) I use `textureList["ImageTitle"]` to grab the texture I desire.

My question is: Is this an incredibly inefficient system and am I just trying to reinvent the wheel? Should I just go back to having a vast list of variables to store my textures, or is there a better option?

Comment: No.  I think your approach is a solid one.

Comment: I don't think you will, but if you do one day find out that this dictionary approach is the bottleneck of your application, only then you should worry about that.

Comment: I think your code sample won't compile, because Dictionary<TKey, TValue> does not have an Add method that takes 1 argument. But other than that, the approach with caching the textures in a Dictionary isn't bad at all.

Comment: @george.zakaryan You're most certainly right, I just missed out the TKey (It was just a mockup method, not a rip from my actual code). Well spotted :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is: Is this an incredibly inefficient system and am I just trying to reinvent the wheel? Should I just go back to having a vast list of variables to store my textures, or is there a better option?

A dictionary is not inefficient.  Fetching from a dictionary is a relatively fast operation.

The largest drawback to this is you lose compile time safety (if you type the wrong name, it'll be a runtime error, not a compile time error), but otherwise, this is a very common, good approach.  For items that you will fetch and use regularly which are hard-coded within the code, I would recommend making [constants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx) to hold the names instead of repeating the string literals.

This gives you the nice "variables" to use when appropriate, but the flexibility of adding extra items as needed without having to change your code.

Comment: So instead of always doing 'textureList["ImageTitle"]' I'd do something like 'public const string imgVar = "ImageTitle"' then call the texture using 'textureList[imgVar]'?

Comment: @user1363526 Yes, for the ones you're using frequently.

Comment: But surely if I'm calling this, for instance, every tick, it'd be MUCH more efficient to just have a variable holding the image. By efficient I mean the benefits of having an easier layout has been outweighed by the extra ms being added on.

Comment: @user1363526 Yes, if you're reusing the variable constantly, keeping a reference is potentially more useful.  It's likely not going to be "MUCH" more efficent - more "slightly" more efficient, but you could always profile the app to see.  Dictionary lookups are very fast.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a dictionary for looking up textures (while loading) is a great idea, but 
I think you shouldn't use a name to lookup the texture during rendering, only look it up ones, then hold a reference to it, so you can use it directly when rendering.

While loading you can create something like a cache:

```
Texture2D texture;

if(!textureList.TryGetValue(title, out texture))
{
    texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>(title);
    textureList.Add(title, texture);
}

MyNewLoadedMesh.Texture = texture;
```

Comment: But doesn't this just pretty much mean I'd have to create a variable for the reference anyway? What I mean is that currently I'd just be doing Draw(textureList["Image"]... which replaces the need to have a list of variables. But in order for me to make a reference every tick, I'd need a variable. Correct?

Comment: I meant, when drawing a Mesh, you should have a wrapper object like `MyModel` that holds a reference to the mesh/vertexbuffer and a Texture2D, not to a title of a texture. Because looking up that texture everytime you want to draw it, would be very inefficient. (compared to a reference) But compared to a List, it will be much faster. I would only use that dictionary when 'binding' the texture objects to MyModels. Like a cache.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I make a `Manager<T>` class, which is basically a wrapper around two dictionary objects, with objects T indexed by an ID number and a name. A naïve implementation would look like:

```
public class Manager<T>
{
    private Dictionary<int, T> IndexByID;
    private Dictionary<string, T> IndexByName;

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return this.IndexByID[index]; }
    }

    public T this[string index]
    {
        get { return this.IndexByName[index]; }
    }

    public void Add(int id, string name, T value)
    {
        this.IndexByID[id] = value;
        this.IndexByName[name] = value;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how efficient this approach is, but it *makes the most sense to me*.

Comment: Why would you need to index it using an int and a string, surely you'd only need one, right? Sounds like it's just doing unnecessary operations, but I'm not too bright when it comes to optimising code.

Comment: I usually load my textures by name like `"tx_wall"` or what have you. The only reason int is there is so that I could iterate them, but I suppose that the `Dictionary<>` would do that if you generated a `TValue` collection and then turned it into a List<>. Not sure how expensive that would be, but I figure a little extra memory used makes up for the performance.